# Intel ME equivalent in Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, apple, backdoor

So AMD and Intel have built-in autonomous subsystems that have the ability to spy on users (IME and PSP). I heard that Apple has some new thing that scans the files that users store on their servers to look for illegal photographs, and I speculate that will soon be used to look for more than crime.

But besides this, is it known that Apple has any other spying —ware in the Apple Silicon Mac? I’m not asking ‘whether it is likely full of spying devices’, but rather ‘which spying services that are known on Apple silicon’.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to be about the use or administration of Unix or Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: Note that although macOS is indeed on topic, mac hardware is not, unless the question is about the relationship between a *nix system (such as macOS) and said hardware. The internal details of the hardware, however, are not something we cover here. You might have better luck over at our sister site: [apple.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.macobserver.com/analysis/apple-scans-uploaded-content/

> Apple scans for hashes of known CSAM during its upload into iCloud,
> which is what the term “pre-screening” means as shared above. But now
> they’ve moved this scanning algorithm and hash database locally on
> every device. It’s a clever middle-ground between privacy and
> invasiveness.
>
> It’s not PhotoDNA either; instead Apple created its own technology
> that it calls NeuralHash.
> ...
>
> Bottom line: Despite the scanning done locally it still only scans
> photos uploaded to iCloud Photos. Non-iCloud photos will not be
> affected, nor (I suspect) will photos stored in other places like the
> Files app.

Read Apple's document on this type of scanning here:
https://www.apple.com/child-safety/pdf/Expanded_Protections_for_Children_Frequently_Asked_Questions.pdf

I believe this is what you are thinking of, that's on their 'cloud' storage, not local, so you didn't hear it quite correctly. A rarely understood component of all 'cloud' based storage (not just cloud, any server type storage that isn't under your control) is that there are basically no privacy rights on that at all, unlike stuff on your personal devices.

This also applies to all cloud based storage of emails etc as well. It's always interesting/fascinating to see people concerned about genuine privacy issues happily feed large corporations their data as if it were on their private systems, like Facebook, Google, Apple, etc.

I could not find anything on hardware based vulnerabilities, but that could just be because it doesn't hit the news the way Intel/AMD stuff does. But I do recall that recently the NSA had to hire an Israeli firm to crack the encryption on an Iphone they had seized, which suggests strongly that there are no backdoors that are readily accessible on those Apple devices. They had initially tried to force Apple to hand over tools to break the encryption, and Apple, to their credit, refused, because to do so would have exposed all their user's iphones to such snooping.

But it's always worth tracking this stuff. Keep in mind however, it's not just hardware based items that can be used in this way, firmware blobs can also be used to do this type of crack, like for wifi, bluetooth, etc.

**Patriot Act**

It's worth reading / learning the actual protections and other rights the Patriot Act removed under the guise of fighting terrorism, basically if the government issues a subpoena for data on a server, the company has almost no recourse, they have to supply it, and, what's worse, they are not allowed to reveal this request, or face legal consequences.

There was a well known secure email service that abruptly shut its doors without a word, and wiped their entire systems. Everyone understood that they had received such a demand, and chose to terminate their service without warning rather than compromise their core business ethics, but they could never actually say this in public.

You'll notice that Amazon, Microsoft, Apple, Google, etc, are all still in business, which means they do comply with all such requests when they are made (for remote server/cloud based user data).

Comment: Thanks. Can’t upvote because I haven’t earned enough reputation yet.